# Good/free tool or way to backup drivers

Tags: windows, backup, windows-vista, drivers

What is good free tool to backup all currently installed hardware drivers, or is there manual way to do it too?
Also, simple way to restore backed up collection of drivers to fresh reinstalled system, if suggested tool doesn't support that functionallity.

I'm looking for solution on Windows Vista, all editions.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give [DriverBackup!](https://sourceforge.net/projects/drvback/) a shot. Free and Open Source.

> Fast and user-friendly free tool for
>   drivers's backup, restoration and
>   removal with command line options,
>   automatic restoration from CD\DVD and
>   path formatting. DriverBackup!
>   includes also an interactive command
>   line builder.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Double Driver](http://www.boozet.org/dd.htm) is pretty smart and free.

(original credit to [Matt Simmons](http://www.standalone-sysadmin.com/blog/2009/01/use-double-driver-to-simplify-your-next-reinstall/))

Answer (score 0):

http://www.innovative-sol.com/drivermax/ works really great.  In addition to exporting and backing up your drivers, and downloading the latest updates.  DriverMax only works on Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP and Windows 2003