# Imaging Sony Viaos -- Missing drivers

Tags: windows, drivers, laptop, image, ghost

I've been given several Sony Viao VGN-BX760's from old software engineering students. I'm supposed to install Windows, drivers, necessary software, and image the other laptops with it. The problem is Sony's drivers from their own website are broken.

Even after installing every driver listed on Sony's support page, there are two VGA Controllers without drivers, an Unknown Device, and the optical drive driver says "no device is connected." What it means is, the device I'm compatible with must not be here. I know the drive works, I installed XP from it. Sony either has the wrong driver, or gosh, I don't know.

So are there other ways to get drivers? If these other Viaos are working, is it possible to rip drivers from them? Thanks.

Edit: To the best of my knowledge, we do not have the original system discs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a machine with working drivers you could have a look at [these](https://serverfault.com/questions/32208/good-free-tool-or-way-to-backup-drivers/32236#32236) answers.

Answer (score 0):

Something to check for is a hidden recovery partition.  I just reloaded a Vaio using that, and that saves you the hassle of tracking down drivers.  One of the function keys should trigger the recovery or a boot menu where you can select the recovery from.  I am a huge fan of this since I have had a number of laptops with no image or support disks handed off to me for reloading, and we don't have VLKs.  A quick check on google indicates that it might be F-10.

Comment: Eep, except I had to DBAN the computer to protect sensitive research data.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at something like Everest and use it to find the real device models so you can search them up from the original device manufactures compared to the sony website.